# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm working on a project on jupyter notebook and when using the line `from library.sb_utils import save_file` it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'`. i have a suspicion that the problem lies with the env path, but not too sure. I'm fairly new to python, especially new to env and paths, not fully understanding it. How do I get it to work? I've tried changing the paths to see if the location of something was the problem, but not sure if I made it worse or not. I did try pip install library, but its already there. I tried pip3 install as well and its already there. I'm using windows 11 and python 3.11.7.

Comment: What is your folder structure for this project? (suggest adding this to your question with an edit to the question).

Comment: Did you try `python3.11 -m pip install library`?

Comment: Did you try `%pip install library` run in a new cell where you want to use it & then restart kernel? The modern magic commands for installs are current **universal** best practice in all Jupyter and even Google Colab now. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. **It is an easier way to do what `9769953` is recommending.**

Comment: <continued> Oh wait, only try that if the package is at Python Package Index (PyPi). If it is local, forget what I said. I'll leace what I said there because I'm not sure since you mention `pip install` and what I said though is the modern convenient way to do something like `9769953` is suggesting and so it may come in handy elserwhere if you weren't already using the magic install commands.

Answer (score -1):

on things you provide, i think you can try some things like:

1. First

The module is not installed: You mentioned that you’ve tried pip install library and pip3 install library, and both commands indicate that the module is already installed. However, it’s possible that the module is installed in a different Python environment than the one Jupyter is using. You can check it with

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This will print the path to the Python executable that Jupyter is using. You can then install the module to that Python environment by running the following command in your terminal (replace /path/to/python with the path printed by the above command):

```
/path/to/python -m pip install library
```

2. Second thing,

The module is not in the Python path: Python uses the PYTHONPATH environment variable to determine where to look for modules to import. If the module is installed but not in a location that’s included in the PYTHONPATH, Python won’t be able to find it. Can be checked:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

If the path to the module is not included in the PYTHONPATH, you can add it using the following command in your terminal (replace /path/to/module with the path to the directory containing the module):

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/module"
```

you can try it, i hope to work for you